# How to count the different paths in a graph given a source node and a path length

Tags: python, graph

I have a simple graph with 4 nodes `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` as well as the following edges:

```
[A,B]
[B,D]
[B,C]
```

I want to find paths that start at the node C given a certain length `n`. For example:

for `n = 1` I will only have `[C]` as a possible path. Result is 1

for `n = 2` we only have `[C,B]`. Result is 1

for `n = 3` we have `[C,B,C]` , `[C,B,D]`, `[C,B,A]`. Result is 3

etc.

I have written the following (python) code:

```
dg = {'A':['B'],
      'B':['C','D','A'],
      'D':['B'],
      'C':['B']}

beg = ['C']


def makePath(n):
    count = 0
    curArr = beg
    for i in range(n):
        count = len(curArr)
        tmp = []
        for i in curArr:
            tmp.extend(dg[i])
        curArr = tmp
    return count
```

However it gets extremely slow above `n=12`. Is there a better algorithm to solve this and more importantly. one that can be generalized for any undirected graph (i.e. with up to 20 nodes)?

Comment: ```[B,C]``` is an edge, ```C``` can always only go to ```B```

Comment: Oh, I see, they're undirected edges. That matches your bottom graph. Thanks. BTW, your code runs fast up to `n = 25` or so for me.

Comment: @ggorlen might be more raw power, I’m running this on my laptop :) I think the above algorithm in C could run fast up to even n=50-100 but that doesn’t make it more efficient/scalable